# Extensive Image in Web design

Tags: javascript, css, web

I am coding a website and trying to have something like www.airbnb.com : I mean a static bar on the top (this part is ok) and a big image just below with a big centered button.

How can I manage to have this big image appearing normally on every screen resolution: for the moment, on 1920*1080px my image is just perfect with the big button centered. But, if i change my resolution, the image will be cropped or resized...

Do you know how can I do that (css or javascript) ?

Thank you so much !

Comment: `img { width: 100%; }` would proportially scale your image to whatever container it is in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS media queries to load a physically different sized image depending on the resolution e.g.

Your original desktop background:

```
body {
    background:url(images/bg1.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

For screens with a max resolution of 800px:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {

    body {
        background:url(images/bg2.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    }

}
```

For screens with a max resolution of 480px:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {

    body {
        background:url(images/bg3.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    }

}
```

The resolution you choose are obviously up to yourself and the above are only given as examples.

Comment: I tried this and it is working. Is it compatible with all navigators ?

Comment: @AlexGrs - Do you mean browsers? If so the yes, it's compatible with most browsers. Please see this link: http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

Comment: Yes I wanted to say "browser" sorry for that :-) !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<img>`, then set the `width` and `height` attributes to it.

If you are using the image as a background to an existing element, set the correct [styles](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) for the background:

```
div{
  background:url(img_flwr.gif);
  background-size:80px 60px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that the above solution relies on the CSS3 background-size property which won't work in older, non-CSS3 compatible, browsers.